# Android: required android.support.v7.app.ActionBar found android.app.ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to use the **getActionBar();** method and I receive this error:  required android.support.v7.app.ActionBar found android.app.ActionBar . How can I correct this?

Comment: it is not a duplicate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error is occurring because you are creating an object and passing it to a different class reference variable. Because `getActionManager` gives the object of `android.app.ActionBar` but you are trying to assign `android.app.ActionBar` class object to `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`.

But both these classes provide the same functionality. `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` Class is used when our uses-sdk min version is less the api 11. to get the object of ActionBar below api 11 we need `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` class object.

To get Action bar you need to follow one of two approaches.

1. `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` and use `getSupportActionBar()` method od activity.
2. go to AndroidManifest.xml file and change `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"  android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`
   and import `android.app.ActionBar` and use `getActionBar()`

Answer (score 1):

If supporting API levels lower than 11 and you will have to add the support v4 library in your project to used an actionbar.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
```

If supporting only API level 11 and higher:

```
import android.app.ActionBar
```

For more information go to [Official Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have minimum api level in your manifest file is above 11. Because the package `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` is only supported in api level below 11.

So if you want to use an ActionBar from `import android.app.ActionBar` then you must be having minimun api level 11 in your manifest file. Otherwise you will have to add the support v4 library in your project to user an actionbar from `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` package.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app has app bar or title bar, check you app theme at manifest file or at your style.xml
if in your style like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- your style -->
</style>
```

It will fine when use `ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();`

But if on your style like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<!-- your style-->
</style>
```

it will throw null exception when use `ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();`

Make sure you use `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`

Answer (score -1):

If running api 11 and higher

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
```

also if it states that it already exists be sure to remove it

Comment: This is already mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27482395/711006).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.