# ActionBar error "incompatible types"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I am stuck with making tabs using ActionBar. When I make it to run app with some code changes, my app crashes instantly without even starting. The current code is closest to working where I could get. This is MainActivity here:

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ActionBar actionbar;
    ViewPager viewpager;
    FragmentPageAdapter ft;
    FragmentPageAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ft = new FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mAdapter = new FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        //final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        //final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        actionbar = getActionBar();

        viewpager.setAdapter(ft);
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("DotNet").setTabListener(this));
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Eal").setTabListener(this));
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Neowin").setTabListener(this));
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("PcWorld").setTabListener(this));
        viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }



    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: try: getSupportActionBar(); instead of : getActionBar();

Comment: tried that. Then it says "Cannot resolve method 'getSupportActionBar()' "

Comment: small comment: When the firstly described error appears the code 
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); is underlined in red. In the second case when I type "final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();" this part of code "getSupportActionBar();" is in red.

Comment: leave as getSupportActionBar as I said and extend AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity

Comment: I get more code in red saysing "Cannot resolve symbol/method" including AppCompatActivity itself. Now I am going to look for other tutorials using ActionBar and see where does it get me.

Comment: I found this very useful SO link in which there are some details about correct importing of ActionBar:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482381/android-required-android-support-v7-app-actionbar-found-android-app-actionbar
Now I got rid of "android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;" and added "import android.app.ActionBar;" because in this link it says that "If supporting only API level 11 and higher: use "android.app.ActionBar" . Since it solved this code " actionbar = getActionBar(); " by not showing it in red anymore I get another error with MainActivity naming. Gonna try to edit main message.